# Requirements for Visa from Pakistan to Taiwan to go to China

Tags: visas, transit, china, pakistani-citizens, taiwan

A couple of my colleagues and I are planning to go to China(Hangzhou) in a few to months to attend a conference, the flights to China whether direct or otherwise are a out of out budget, so we only have 2 modes of action, either go by road by taking the bus offered as part of Pak-China corridor to enter China and then take trains the rest of the way through but it will take too much time(around 4 days one way), or to take a flight to Taiwan, and then take a ferry to China, and then take the train the rest of the way.

Now, we have the necessary documents to get the visa for China(and we will get it no doubt) like the invitation letter and whatnot. But we don't know if we can get the visa to Taiwan using these documents or not, and if we can even get a visa to Taiwan for such a reason. So, can you please guide me a bit on this? Whether we can get this visa or not and what we need to get it.

Comment: I am very surprised that you say air tickets to Taiwan are so much cheaper than tickets to Hangzhou. For a quick search that I did, I found the tickets to Hangzhou were cheaper! You might want to spend some more time searching for fares.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your response, can you tell me which airline you searched for, because in all my search the cost to any airport in China was around double compared to what it was for Taipei.

Comment: Hm, I was seeing cheap fares on China Southern but they were this month, when I search for fares in October they are gone. I searched for 9-16 October, and found the cheapest return fares ISB-HGH for Rs. 111,938, and ISB-TPE was Rs. 78,418. So I think you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taiwan's Bureau of Consular Affairs maintains [a webpage](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-159-249-4162c-2.html) where visa information for the Republic of China (R.O.C., or Taiwan) is presented in English. That page contains the following, which sets requirements for a Pakistani citizen (as well as citizens of the other 16 countries listed, which names I've omitted from this Answer) to obtain a visa to enter Taiwan.

"Nationals from the following countries applying for visitor visas to the R.O.C. must fulfill the procedure of this section：

...

"Pakistan

...

"Nationals of the designated countries may apply for the R.O.C. visitor visas for  the following purposes：

- Invited by the Republic of China (R.O.C.) government agencies on
  official missions
- Participating in international meetings or activities for the
  purposes of  religious, athletic, or cultural exchange, which are
  held by the organizations set up in the R.O.C.
- Visiting dependents with legal residence status in the R.O.C.,
  including spouse, family members of  lineal relationship, or
  siblings.
- Conducting economic or commercial businesses.（including accompanied
  spouse and children...
- Crew members intending to come to the R.O.C. to report for duty.
- Medical treatment."

Unless your planned trip to Taiwan fits within one of these six categories, you will not quaify for a visa.